# If the value of list 1 is the index of list 2, how can I sort list 1 according to the list 2 value

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose there is a list a[i] which stores index value v, v is the index value of  another list b[v]. I want to according to the values of list b to sort the list a.
For example
a=[0,2,3,1]  b=[7,10,8,6] 
I want the list a become a=[1,2,0,3], is there some concise way to sort list a?

Comment: Would you want `a` to be `[1,0,3,2]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
[x for _,x in sorted(zip(b,a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the items in a using a key.  That key is a function of each element of a.

Try this:

`a = sorted(a, key=lambda i: b[i])`

Note that if any value in `a` is outside the range of `b`, this would fail and raise an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Based on your description, however, you want the list to be sorted in reverse order, so:

`a = sorted(a, key=lambda i: b[i], reverse=True)`

Answer (score -1):

Simply solution would be sort the list b first and then get the indexes for list b after sorting, finally get the values of a list in the order of b indexes that were taken after sorting b list